# Cannot curl to another vm's ports using bridged connection in VirtualBox

Tags: curl, networking, virtualbox

I am new to VirtualBox and am trying to learn docker containers. So, I have two virtual machines, A and B, both running ubuntu 16.04 xenial and they have a bridged connection in between them. In A, I have a docker container running nginx on port 80. Now, what i am trying to do is send a curl request from B to port 80 of A.
A's ip address is 130 while B is 129.
I can ping both of them from each other.
Now when i curl from inside A, I get:
[image]

When i try to curl from B, I get:
[image]

However, when I change the network from bridged to internal, i can easily curl to port 80 of A from B.
I do not need a workaround, i just want to know why this is happening and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if firewall is active on your VM. You can allow TCP Port 80 on Ubuntu using :

sudo ufw allow80/tcp

You need to allow it in VM A